# Bootstrap datepicker wrong format and language

Tags: symfony, locale, sonata-admin, bootstrap-datepicker, symfony-sonata

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) to select a date with SonataAdminBundle. It all works with two exceptions:

1. it shows month names in language what could be French, while English is expected.
2. it uses data format dd.mm.yyyy, when it is setup to use yyyy-mm-dd format.

This is how I initialize the Datepicker on my page:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/standard_layout.html.twig' %}            
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dp_options = {
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                language: 'en',
                locale: 'en'
                };
        $('.js-datepicker').datepicker(dp_options);
    });
</script>  
{% endblock %}
```

The application is in Symfony 4 with SonataAdminBundle.

Anyway, what am I missing?

Comment: Try setting locale to 'fr'. Format option looks fine though.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is that I want it to show up in English.